# Undefined subroutine Win32::MSgBox when trying to install Win32::Watir on Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, module

I am trying to install Win32::Watir on to a 64 bit machine via strawberry perl. I'm getting an error. This is a windows automation tool - so it should have be to be able to be installed on a windows machine via strawberry perl.

reports SHIMI/Win32-Watir-0.06-withoutworldwritebles.tar.gz

```
cpan> install Win32::Watir
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Database was generated on Wed, 29 Jul 2015 22:17:00 GMT
Updating database file ...
Done!
Running install for module 'Win32::Watir'
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/S/SH/SHIMI/Win32-Watir-0.06-withoutworldwriteables.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/S/SH/SHIMI/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for C:\UBS\DEV\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\S\SH\SHIMI\Win32-Watir-0.06-withoutworldwriteables.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\UBS\DEV\STRAWB~1\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Configuring S/SH/SHIMI/Win32-Watir-0.06-withoutworldwriteables.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good 
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Win32::Watir
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  SHIMI/Win32-Watir-0.06-withoutworldwriteables.tar.gz
  C:\UBS\DEV\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for S/SH/SHIMI/Win32-Watir-0.06-withoutworldwriteables.tar.gz
cp lib/Win32/Watir/Table.pm blib\lib\Win32\Watir\Table.pm
cp lib/Win32/Watir/AutoItX3.dll blib\lib\Win32\Watir\AutoItX3.dll
cp lib/Win32/Watir.pm blib\lib\Win32\Watir.pm
cp lib/Win32/Watir/AutoItX.chm blib\lib\Win32\Watir\AutoItX.chm
cp lib/Win32/Watir/AutoItX3_x64.dll blib\lib\Win32\Watir\AutoItX3_x64.dll
cp lib/Win32/Watir/Element.pm blib\lib\Win32\Watir\Element.pm
  SHIMI/Win32-Watir-0.06-withoutworldwriteables.tar.gz
  C:\UBS\DEV\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
 Running make test
"C:\UBS\DEV\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest:    :Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.tt/01.IE_default.t .. 1/? DEBUG:_check_os_name(): Win7

Undefined subroutine &Win32::MSgBox called at  
C:\UBS\DEV\STRAWB~\cpan\build\Win32-Watir-0.062RxegT\blib\lib/Win32/Watir.pm line 1370.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 1.
t/01.IE_default.t .. Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
All 1 subtests passed
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/01.IE_default.t (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 1 Failed: 0)
   Non-zero exit status: 255
 Files=1, Tests=1,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr +  0.11 sys =  0.13 CPU)
 Result: FAIL
 Failed 1/1 test programs. 0/1 subtests failed.
 dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
   SHIMI/Win32-Watir-0.06-withoutworldwriteables.tar.gz
   C:\UBS\DEV\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
  //hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
   reports SHIMI/Win32-Watir-0.06-withoutworldwriteables.tar.gz
 Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Win32::Watir'.
 Failed during this command:
 SHIMI/Win32-Watir-0.06-withoutworldwriteables.tar.gz: make_test NO
cpan> sudo install Win32::Watir
Unknown shell command 'sudo'. Type ? for help.
cpan>
```

Comment: The module does `use Win32` and expects to find a `MsgBox` subroutine in there but fails. Do you have your own `Win32.pm` file for some reason? Or is your version on `Win32` out of date?

Comment: @Borodin it seems like it's actually looking for MSgBox with capital s.

Answer (score 1):

The module calls `Win32::MSgBox` when it should have called `Win32::MsgBox`.